# cTAKES indication that category > 0 sources are about to be used?

Tags: ctakes

In appendix 1 of the [UMLS license agreement](https://uts.nlm.nih.gov/license.html), there is a listing of all sources within the current version of the UMLS Metathesaurus with an indication of any additional restrictions and notices that apply. Loosely speaking, it seems like you can generally have your way with the Metathesaurus data sources that fall within category-0 of the license, but things get more restrictive at categories above that.

For example (likely a bad example as I am not a lawyer), looking at section 12.2 of the main license section:

> LICENSEE is prohibited from using the vocabulary source in operational
>   applications that create records or information containing data from
>   the vocabulary source. Use for data creation research or product
>   development is allowed.

My question then is: (since cTAKES already has my UMLS credentials) is there any way to tell when doing a certain action with cTAKES is going to instruct it use/access data from the Metathesaurus that have a category > 0 (eg. some popup warning or header comment in the binary files)? Thanks

** The reason I'm interested is because: suppose that a certain ctakes process uses a category-2 data source to do something on some input that populates data into some XMI output (I don't know much about ctakes' full implementation, but for sake of arg. lets assume this is true) that gets post-processed and stored as some report for an organization. It would seem that the organization has violated the category-2 restriction inadvertently (since they were never warned about the underlying data being used to generate the outputs). I may be grossly misunderstanding something here, so please let me know if this is the case.

Comment: What information are more restrictive you feel?

Comment: @Gandhi Please see the example I have added to the original question